# How Can I Set DataGridViewCellEventArgs As Handled?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling, datagridviewcolumn

I want to mark a [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?view=netframework-4.8) as handled so that nothing downstream from it interferes with the way it was handled.

The [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?view=netframework-4.8) class does not have a handled property, and neither does its base class.

The event that I am working with is[`CellMouseEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseenter?view=netframework-4.8)

This is the base `DataGridView` control that I am instantiating from:

```
public class DataGridViewWithFormatting : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellMouseEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellMouseEnter(e);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

This is the `DataGridView` control that I am using in my form:

```
private CustomControls.DataGridViewWithFormatting dgvItems;
```

and...

```
dgvItems.CellMouseEnter += new EventHandler(dgvItems_CellMouseEnter);
```

then...

```
private void dgvItems_CellMouseEnter()
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Comment: `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` doesn't have any `Handled` or `Cancel` property, so if you want to stop event propagation, you need to override the method which raises the event and do not call base method.

Comment: What's the requirement, there may be some other solutions if we know the requirement.

Comment: @JohnG I updated the description with the event (`CellMouseEnter`).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am trying to modify the mouse cursor when it enters the cell, but the other `CellMouseEnter` event that fires after mine overrides my mouse cursor setting/change.

Comment: Could you clarify it a bit more? What kind of cell? What cursor? Also it would be great if you can share a [MCVE]. It will help us to reproduce the problem and makes sure we are on the same page, trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following solutions depending on your requirements.

**1 - Use BeginInvoke**

To set the cursor in `CellMouseEnter`, you can use [`BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
private void Dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dgv.Cursor = Cursors.Hand));
}
```

**2 - Create a new cancellable(handle-able) `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`**

Create a new `MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs` event args deriving from [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) having a `Handled` property. Then in your derived `DataGridView`, when calling `base.OnCellMouseEnter`, pass an instance of the new cancellable(handle-able) event args. In the event handlers, still keep the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` in the signature. To cancel, cast it to `MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs` and cancel it by setting `Handled = true;`:

```
public class DataGridViewWithFormatting : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellMouseEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var myE = new MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs(e);
        base.OnCellMouseEnter(myE);
        if (!myE.Handled)
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
public class MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs : DataGridViewCellEventArgs
{
    public bool Handled { get; set; } = false;
    public MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        : base(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) { }
}
```

And the event handler:

```
private void Dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    var myE = e as MyDataGridViewCellEventArgs;
    if (myE != null)
        myE.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I prefer second solution.